# Can I escape a color code in Powershell so I do not need to use -ForeGroundColor?

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to use some color-code escape character so that I do not need to mention -ForeGroundColor parameter?

So instead of :

```
write-Host "Hello World!" -ForegroundColor:Blue
```

Can I do something like:

```
write-Host "Hello \{somethinghere to denote from this point it will be in BLUE color} World!"
```

Comment: Are you looking to change colour in mid text then? That can be done but you still need to set the parameters and needs fancy use of `-NoNewLine`. Making a function would be the answer there but I am sure that has occured to you.

Comment: You're probably thinking of ANSI escape sequences. AFAIK PowerShell doesn't support these. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30178582/1630171) might help, though.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers That is a nice find. Code needs an update though.... all those `if`'s....

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers actually they _are_ supported (at least meanwhile). See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65250633/4776207) below. So no workaround is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that gets around powershell not supporting ANSI escape codes.

This should allow you to specify what character you use as a delimiter

```
function Write-Colored {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=1)]
        [string]$text,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=2)]
        [string]$delimiter
    )


    $i = $text.Split($delimiter)

    function pr ([string]$item, [System.ConsoleColor]$color){
        Write-Host $item.Substring(1) -fore $color -NoNewline
    }

    foreach ($item in $i){
        $colorcode = $item.ToCharArray()[0]

        switch($colorcode){
            "b" { pr $item Blue }
            "r" { pr $item Red }
            "g" { pr $item Green }
            "y" { pr $item Yellow }
            default { Write-Host $item -NoNewline }
        }
    }
}
```

in the switch block, add whatever shorthand codes you want to correspond to a certain color. I picked single characters since its easier to validate against, and the results are as follows:

## input:

```
$text = "#rmy #gname #yis #bchris"
```

## outputs something like

[image]

just keep in mind, while using this helper function, you will need to use

```
`n
```

for adding newlines to your text, or add a `write-host ""` to the bottom of your function if desired.

Edit: Revised code to be a little more reliable

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used your function and works as I have expected and very simple to apply.

Comment: Among all workarounds, this was the simplest and best written.

Answer (score 3):

A very basic approach that I would take for this would be to make a dedicated function that will look for special strings that contain colour information. This does not have much in the way of validation but it works as proof of concept assuming I know what you are trying to do.

```
Function Write-HostFormatted{
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $text,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [alias("DefaultColour")]
        [System.ConsoleColor]$Colour
    )

    $text -split "({[^}]+})" | ForEach-Object{
        If($_ -match "({[^}]+})"){
            # We need to change the colour
            $Colour = $_.Trim("{}")
        } else {
            # Output text using the current colour
            Write-Host -NoNewline $_ -ForegroundColor $Colour
        }
    }
    # Add the trailing newline
    Write-Host ""
}
```

Then you could call it like this:

```
Write-HostFormatted "This text is{Blue} Blue!{Red} Now this text is Red" White
```

[image: Output example]

If this was something you were actually interested in I would rewrite it as I think there is large room for improvement. Point being is that you would have to create a custom function to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $PSDefaultParameterValues to set the default color.

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Write-Host:ForegroundColor'] = 'Blue'
```

Comment: Havent seen you in a while. I suspect that the OP is wanting to change this more dynamically but need him to chime in first.

Answer (score 0):

Actually (at least of now) no workaround is needed as Powershell *does* support ANSI escape codes.

So this wll do the trick:

```
Write-Host "Hello $([char]27)[34mWorld"
```

And if you are not into escape sequencs you can define some variables to mak your life easier:

```
$esc=$([char]27)
$blue="$esc[34"
$normal="$esc[0"

Write-Host "Hello$blue World$normal!"
Write-Host "Hello $($blue)World$normal!"
```

This excellent [post](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/how-to-use-ansi-vt100-formatting-in-powershell-ooh-pretty-colors/) shows more and includes a list of the most common color codes.

I can just add the observation, that some extended codes like **bold** are ignored in older versions of Windows (Windows Server 2016) while the colors work just fine.