# How to enable output text highlighting in IPython on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, ipython, windows-console

I'm trying to highlight part of my output in the Windows console as follows:

```
print 'Matches:'+'\033[0;33m'+str(123)+'\033[0;0m'
```

It works fine in a Linux terminal, but under Windows it shows

```
>>>Matches:[0;33m123[0;0m
```

How can I enable highlighting in the Windows console?

PS: I think there should be a way to do this because it works with `raw_input`. For example:

[image: windows powershell, ipython enviroment]
[image: ipython]

Comment: A quick search here on SO tells me Powershell does not support ANSI escape codes. [It showed some alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36428238/2564301), though.

Comment: @RadLexus, there should be some way, because when I use rawinput('\033[46m see me \033[0;0m'), it works fine

Comment: In your first image you're using IPython, and the second image is just the Python REPL. Most likely it's IPython that doesn't support ANSI escape sequences.

Comment: @MattDMo, no, I tried both of them, even in ipython I raw_input() works fine

Comment: You aren't in cmd/PowerShell. The console server and window are hosted by an instance of conhost.exe. The shell is waiting in the background, while python.exe is the foreground client. IPython uses the pyreadline module to print ANSI escape sequences on Windows, which in turn uses the [console API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073). IPython doesn't replace `sys.stdout`, so `print` is using the original `sys.stdout`, but you can use IPython's pyreadline stream instead: `from IPython.utils.io import stdout;` `stdout.write('Matches:'+'\033[0;33m'+str(123)+'\033[0;0m')`.

Comment: If you want general support for ANSI in the console, you can use [ANSICON](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon) or [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io). Also, integrated terminal emulation is coming down the pike for Windows 10, as a conhost.exe enhancement to support its new Linux subsystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried a method, mentioned by @eryksun, thanks for your help.

```
from IPython.utils.io import stdout;
stdout.write('Matches:'+'\033[0;33m'+str(123)+'\033[0;0m')
```

Here is the outout:
[image]

For further discussion, I find that even in pure python shell, the raw_input() works fine to highlight the text, but stdout.write is not working any more. 
Here is the python shell output:
[image]