# Powershell terminal color output when using Get-Content is incorrect, why?

Tags: shell, powershell, scripting

I have a log file that has color encoding baked into it, and I want to "follow the tail" of the log file with Powershell.  When I call the following script, Powershell launches with its standard blue background, and the colors that are encoded in the log file do show up.

```
Get-Content -Path 'C:\myapp.out' -Wait
```

However, what I want is for the background of the Powershell terminal to be black, but keep the color encoding found in the log file.  So, after doing some research, I found you can change aspects of the Powershell terminal, and my script changed into this:

```
$host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Log Title"
$host.ui.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "black"

Clear-Host

Get-Content -Path 'C:\myapp.out' -Wait
```

The background of the Powershell terminal does in fact change to black, but it seems like the output of Get-Content still has the blue background from the standard Powershell.  So, after more research, I learned I could do something like:

```
$host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Log Title"
$host.ui.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "black"

Clear-Host

Get-Content -Path 'C:\myapp.out' -Wait  | ForEach { write-host $_ -BackgroundColor "black"}
```

Now, this does changes things a bit, but does not make each and every line from the `myapp.out` file have a black background.  It seems as though some of the lines from the `myapp.out` are output with a black background color, but some are not.

I looked at [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132140/colour-coding-get-content-results?rq=1), but this did not solve the issue completely.  I just want the blue background from the `Get-Content` command to be black.  Why is this happening, and how can I solve the issue?

Any suggestions?

-- EDIT --

I'm attaching an image of the output.  So you all can see it.

[image: Strangely colored output in Powershell]

I think parsing the file is best since it already has ANSI colors encoded.  I did see [this stack overflow example of maintaining the ANSI colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583664/how-do-you-enable-powershell-to-interpret-ansi-color-codes-when-using-get-conten), but using the code found there still does not display it accurately.  Here is how I've incorporated it:

```
$host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Log Title"
$host.ui.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "black"

Clear-Host

Get-Content -Path 'C:\myapp.out' -Wait | 
        ForEach { 
            $split = $_.Split([char] 27)
            foreach ($line in $split)
              { if ($line[0] -ne '[')
                  { Write-Host $line }
                else
                  { if     (($line[1] -eq '0') -and ($line[2] -eq 'm')) { Write-Host $line.Substring(3) -NoNewline }
                    elseif (($line[1] -eq '3') -and ($line[3] -eq 'm'))
                      { # normal color codes
                        if     ($line[2] -eq '0') { Write-Host $line.Substring(4) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Black       }
                        elseif ($line[2] -eq '1') { Write-Host $line.Substring(4) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor DarkRed     }
                        elseif ($line[2] -eq '2') { Write-Host $line.Substring(4) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor DarkGreen   }
                        elseif ($line[2] -eq '3') { Write-Host $line.Substring(4) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor DarkYellow  }
                        elseif ($line[2] -eq '4') { Write-Host $line.Substring(4) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor DarkBlue    }
                        elseif ($line[2] -eq '5') { Write-Host $line.Substring(4) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor DarkMagenta }
                        elseif ($line[2] -eq '6') { Write-Host $line.Substring(4) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor DarkCyan    }
                        elseif ($line[2] -eq '7') { Write-Host $line.Substring(4) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Gray        }
                      }
                    elseif (($line[1] -eq '3') -and ($line[3] -eq ';') -and ($line[5] -eq 'm'))
                      { # bright color codes
                        if     ($line[2] -eq '0') { Write-Host $line.Substring(6) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor DarkGray    }
                        elseif ($line[2] -eq '1') { Write-Host $line.Substring(6) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Red         }
                        elseif ($line[2] -eq '2') { Write-Host $line.Substring(6) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Green        }
                        elseif ($line[2] -eq '3') { Write-Host $line.Substring(6) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow      }
                        elseif ($line[2] -eq '4') { Write-Host $line.Substring(6) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Blue        }
                        elseif ($line[2] -eq '5') { Write-Host $line.Substring(6) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Magenta     }
                        elseif ($line[2] -eq '6') { Write-Host $line.Substring(6) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Cyan        }
                        elseif ($line[2] -eq '7') { Write-Host $line.Substring(6) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor White       }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This does "improve" the display of the colored log file, but notice how the tabs seem to be removed on the first line, and the coloring returns to white when it should be a blue:

[image]

I've also added [a gist of a portion of this ANSI colored log](https://gist.github.com/ariestav/89064ad928669c1bb6e9e6b8f98a4e6c) file to understand the source better:

Comment: 1) Text files don't have colors. They're just text. 2) `Write-Host` writes only to the host, not to a file.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of what text files are.  I understand what write-host does, and I'm not interested in outputting to a new file.  I'm interested in displaying the .out file that my app creates within a Powershell terminal window with a black background.

Comment: What does "it seems as though some of the lines are output with a black background color, but some are not" mean?

Comment: I would probably take the regex from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/380772/removing-ansi-color-codes-from-text-stream) and convert it from sed/perl syntax to .Net syntax.

Comment: @BaconBits does the .Net syntax work in Powershell?  I guess I'm not sure of the best way to bring in a regex to this script.  Also, my understanding is that not all regex interpreters work the same way.

Comment: (?) Nothing in your original question said anything about ANSI colorization or parsing a file.

Comment: Apologies for not using "ANSI" in the first line of the original posted question:  "I have a log file that has color encoding baked into it, and..."

Comment: Just about everything .Net works in PowerShell, including .Net's regular expressions by using the `-replace` and `-matches` operators, or otherwise calling `[Regex]::Replace()` directly.  The entirety of the .Net Framework is accessible with PowerShell by design, although the syntax gets pretty wonky sometimes.  You can even download .Net assemblies and add them and call them from PowerShell.

Comment: @BaconBits Any chance you can help with the parsing?  I'm at a loss here as I don't use Powershell all that much, and your help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me as is:

[image: Before Clearing the Host ...]
[image]

If you want a better answer, you'll need to supply some sample data to play with. Also, maybe your actual code. I assume you're parsing the output from `Get-Content` and setting a foreground color; since powershell doesn't understand color encodings.

Comment: Thanks, yes, it works with text in a file that has no ANSI color or tabs.  But I updated the question to show how I'm parsing it now, and a Gist to a portion of the log with the ANSI color encoding.